# Creating a Graph of related entities with the data from Wikidata

Tags: graphs-and-networks, core-language

I've a list of Entities from Wikidata

```
listOfKeys = {"Ambientalismo", "Anoressia", "Aspetto fisico", 
   "Attivismo", "Burocrazia", "COVID-19", "Cambiamento climatico", 
   "Canoni estetici"};

list3 = First[#, Missing["NotFound"]] & /@ (WikidataSearch /@ 
    listOfKeys) //DeleteMissing
```

Then I defined a function to look for the parent of the Entity and apply it to the element of the list:
(this instruction

```
ExternalIdentifier["WikidataID", 
     "P279", <|"Label" -> "SubclassOf"|>]
```

means that the ID is P279 and it's human readable meaning is SubclassOf)

```
findParent := # -> 
   WikidataData[#, 
    ExternalIdentifier["WikidataID", 
     "P279", <|"Label" -> "SubclassOf"|>]] &

Graph[findParent /@ list3]
```

The result first problem is that the graph should connect an entity to another entity, while I get a list of associations between 1 entity and a **list** of entities.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `findParent` as:

```
ClearAll[findParent]
findParent = Thread[# -> WikidataData[#, 
   ExternalIdentifier["WikidataID", "P279", <|"Label" -> "SubclassOf"|>]] ] &; 

edges = Flatten[findParent /@ list3];

Graph[edges, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> 
    (Text[Framed @ Style[#2["Label"] /. _Missing -> #2, Black, 12], #] &), 
 ImageSize -> 900]
```

[image]

Comment: I've created a new question connected to this, may you give me any small hint with it? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275613/clustering-related-entities-using-the-data-from-wikidata